# What comes between onCreate and onStart for Android?

Tags: android, oncreate, onstart

I see from Android Developers (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that there is a nice flowchart showing `onCreate` leading to `onStart` then to `onResume`, and so forth.  My question is: what other `on****()` methods appear in between `onCreate` and `onStart`?

For example, I've been doing research on the topic, and I know other methods such as `onMeasure` and `onSizeChanged`, `onDraw`, and others exists.  Where do they fit in to that flow chart?

Thank you.

Comment: Make an activity that overrides every single one of the onX() and add a single log statement to each. Then run the activity and inspect your log. Will tell you the order that every thing happens in.

Answer (score 2):

The methods you mentioned aren't related to the `Activity` lifecycle.

For instance, it would be incorrect to include the call to `onMeasure` in the `Activity` lifecycle flow chart. `onMeasure` is called whenever the layout changes (i.e. when `requestLayout` is called) or the first time a window is laid out. The call to `onMeasure` isn't *directly* related to the system's calls to `onCreate` and `onStart`.

Answer (score 1):

Those other methods exist, but they don't really fit in any one place on that flowchart, nor are they part of the activity lifecycle. in fact, that's why they're not on the chart. The ones you mentioned are really more of the view lifecycle which is separate from (though admittedly related to) the activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This image can clearly depict what you want.